# Monitor traffic between two network switches using a transparent firewall

Tags: firewall, monitoring, tcpdump, port-mirroring

For debugging reasons i need to see what network traffic especially TCP is transmitted or not.

I thought about using an Endian firewall for this, but it doesn't support 2 network interfaces with the same IP range.

I am looking for a Linux solution which I can plug between the two switches in order to monitor all traffic passing by.

What I found out so far is that I am probably searching for a "transparent firewall" solution.

Comment: Do your switches support port mirroring?

Comment: The "big" Cisco probably but the on desk I have not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for me would be to put a [network tap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_tap) between the switches. You can however put a Linux box with 2 interfaces and set it up as a bridge.

```
# brctl addbr br0
# brctl addif br0 eth0
# brctl addif br0 eth1
# brctl setageing br0 0
# ip link set dev br0 up promisc on
```

Then you can look at the traffic traversing the bridge using `tcpdump` as usual.

```
# tcpdump -i br0
```

Comment: that sounds intersting can i use tcpdump after that to see the traffic going through ?

Comment: Yes you can, `tcpdump -i br0`.

Comment: i am reading to brctl man right now looks intersting, if i read your code i get: 1. Setup broadcast 2. add eth0 3. add eth1 , what to the last 2 lines do ?

Comment: Ageing is the bridge ability to remember of which port as been seen a MAC address. The command prevents deletion and have faster forwarding. It is not mandatory however. The last command is just to bring the bridge up, `promisc on` asks to the kernel to look at every frame even if it is not for the bridge (MAC address) so you can monitor all the traffic.

Comment: ok nice, i am preparing an ubuntu system atm and try it

Comment: seems to work but i dont see logs when i am browsing on the mac mini, with tcpdump, only some other network logs like openvpn

Comment: tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420' -i br0 looks promessing

Answer (score 1):

From your post I understand that:

- One of the two switch is a Cisco switch.
- You only want to monitor traffic between the two switches. Not including traffic from the non-Cisco switch to other destinations.

In this case, connect a machine, linux or otherwise, to your Cisco switch. On the Cisco switch configure port-mirror to copy all packets to the port where your machine is.

On your machine, use tcpdump, wireshark or anything like that.

It does not require a Cisco switch to do that, but any managed switch which has the port monitoring feature.

Answer (score 0):

If its only about monitoring and not filtering a passive network tap device would work.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_tap

http://www.altsec.info/passive-network-tap.html

Comment: i only want to see if traffic is floating or not